# CMake: require building of files in addition to building targets

Tags: cmake, dependencies, code-generation, target

In this simple CMakefile, the first script `list.sh` outputs a list of 2 generated files `file1.proto;file2.proto`, instructing CMake that they can be built from source `source.xml` (using the second script `gen.sh`).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

set(source "source.xml")

execute_process(
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/list.sh ${source}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE protos
)
message("${protos}: ${source}")
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${protos}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen.sh ${source}
  DEPENDS ${source}
)
add_custom_target(my_target DEPENDS ${protos})
```

Everything works well if I run:

```
$ cmake ..
file1.proto;file2.proto: source.xml
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /build

$ make my_target
[100%] Generating file1.proto, file2.proto
[100%] Built target my_target
```

What should I add to be able to also run the code generation with:

```
$ make file1.proto
```

[EDIT] autocomplete suggests only the following for command `make`:

```
$ make  (TAB TAB)
all                       cmake_force               edit_cache/               preinstall                
clean                     default_target            help                      preinstall/               
clean/                    depend                    my_target                 rebuild_cache             
cmake_check_build_system  edit_cache                my_target/                rebuild_cache/
```

Comment: Try `make /the/full/absolute/path/to/file1.proto` posting the absolute path to the file. In most shells pressing `make <tab><tab>` will list all available targets. Literally, do `foreach(i IN LISTS ${protos}) get_filename_compoenent(<extarct filename here>) add_custom_target(the_filename_file1.proto DEPENDS the_full_path_in_protos)` Most probably the full absolute path is used in cmake.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, and I cannot find my 2 files in the autocomplete of `make` (added in the body of the question).

Comment: @KamilCuk feel free to write an answer: if no other is submitted, I will accept yours as the best possible solution.

Comment: good summary of everything that can go wrong when declaring dependencies from/to generated files (TLDR: it's basically not possible): https://samthursfield.wordpress.com/2015/11/21/cmake-dependencies-between-targets-and-files-and-custom-commands/

Answer (score 1):

Solution from @KamilCuk :
Adding the following makes it possible to build each proto file individually
(it works, but then cmake complains about circular dependencies!)

```
foreach(p ${protos})
  add_custom_target(${p} DEPENDS {CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${p})
endforeach()
```